# I want to run program on background . pref C#

Tags: c#

I want to run program on background . pref C#
I want put icon in the tray.
On specified time it’s  synchronizes   folders (I know how to sync folders) . 
How to run it on background and start sync ( for example at  2am)?

Answer (score 3):

You need to consider using the [windows scheduler service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/msdnmag/issues/07/10/WindowsCPP/).

Answer (score 1):

To run "in background"

```
Form.Visible = False
Form.ShowInTaskbar = False
```

To start the synchronization, use a Timer and...

- Check the time every minute, start synch if the time matches
- OR calculate the interval Now->TimeToStart, set it, start the Timer, and reset it to 24 hours on the first tick

You might also think about creating a service if you want it to be a background process only.

Answer (score 1):

I very often use Notify Icon on my applications which comes with Visual Studio, http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3336751 as for start syncing, you can call a function on another thread which will measure time every second and if it is 2am you can call another function in another thread to sync folders (you can use also a timer component).

Resources:

Notify Icon: http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3336751

C# Threading: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Timer Component: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/TimeSheet.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd use the scheduler services in Windows.

Having a service, keeping an icon in the tray, etc. means you'll be filling up valuable screen space and consuming resources. What's more, the user will need some way to configure the application so they can choose whether it starts with Windows or not; if you provide this configuration, it'll be necessarily different to how every other application does it.

A scheduler task, on the other hand, only needs one process - the task scheduler itself - and the user can disable or delete the task themselves. Both the Apple and Google automatic updater processes now run in this way, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you start with a Windows Forms Application, and want it to run in background, hanging from the system tray, you have to create the system tray, hide the main form before Application.Run(MainForm), and you're on.

To hide the form, I use:

```
MainForm.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Minimized;
MainForm.ShowInTaskBar = false;
```

(since setting visible= false will be turned back on by the Run() method.)

To create a System Tray, I used instructions from [here](http://alanbondo.wordpress.com/2008/06/22/creating-a-system-tray-app-with-c/):